# Copy filled html form from browser to document

Tags: copy-paste, forms

I would like to fill an html form with checkboxes in a webpage, then copy it to a word document (or other format), along with the selected checkboxes.

So I can easily have a copy of what I submitted in a searchable format (not a screenshot).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: He might have dozens of pages in a document. Also a screenshot is an image so you can't copy text segments from it anymore.
Finally one of his requirements was: "So I can easily have a copy of what I submitted in a searchable format" which is already the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a pdf printer like [FreePDFXP](http://freepdfxp.de/index_de.html) and print the filled form into a pdf. A pdf document can be searched and indexed and you still have the checked checkboxes in there.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE8. In Chrome, the built in "save as pdf" printer works. A solution that also works in IE would be better, but I will accept this answer if another doesn't appear soon.

Comment: I don't know why the solution wouldn't work in IE8. FreePDFXP and similar tools install a virtual printer into your OS and transform what-ever a program prints into a PDF. I could only imagine that IE8 isn't able to print filled documents at all in which case you are really out of luck.

Comment: Completely off-topic: You really shouldn't be using IE8 anymore, unless explicitly required by some intranet application. It's way to outdated to be used safely anymore. The current version is IE11. This is even more true when running windows XP since MS no longer supports it leaving you vulnerable to any new bug found.